# Trait/Scope for my custom laravel paginate method

Tags: php, laravel

I want to implement my own pagination for vue and laravel, instead of using get like laravel I want to make use POST ajax requests from my custom vue pagination component.

For that I want to implement something similar to a scope I can apply to my Eloquent models, I want that scope to return the total number of records from my model in database and a specific number of records along with it.

With this two data I can hydrate my pagination component, since I'm not really sure how to approach this (use Trait?, a scope?, return JSON? or collection  maybe?) I leave my pseudocode bellow:

```
public function scopeGetPaginate($query, $perPage)
    {

        $pageResults = $query->take($perPage)->get();

        $totalResults = Model::count();

        return response()->json([
            'pageResults' => $pageResults,
            'totalResults' => totalResults,
        ], 200);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I cant understand why are you going to implement custom pagination instead of using Laravel Paginate option.like this

```
$users = User::where('votes', '>', 100)->paginate(15);
```

[Laravel Pagination Document](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/pagination)

However if you really want to create custom pagination your can refer Laravel Pagination Api to get an idea about pagination class.

[Laravel Paginator API Reference](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Contracts/Pagination/Paginator.html)